# Why does VASP fail to compute Spontaneous polarization calculation through berry phase method for semiconductors?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, berry-phase

I am trying to calculate the spontaneous polarization of a semiconducting magnetic 2d material with VASP. The Material has a band gap of 0.28 eV (indirect).
VASP warns that

> "The calculation of the macroscopic polarization by means of the
> Berry-phase expressions (LCALCPOL=.TRUE.) requires your system to be
> insulating. This does not seem to be the case."

Why is this happening despite a finite band gap (with PBE)? Adding to this, since this calculation is at 0K, this semiconductor is effectively insulating for this calculation. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I have uploaded the INCAR, OUTCAR, and BAND_GAP file [here](https://easyupload.io/m/yni3m2) .

Comment: Please see [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5).